# Perl LIBXML : Using findnodes with attributes to reach a node in the xml file

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

The XML file looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<application name="pos">
<artifact id="123" type="war" cycle="Release7-Sprint1">
<jira/>
<jenkins/>
<deployment/>
<scm>
  <transaction id="1234" user="">
    <file name=""/>
    <file name=""/>
  </transaction>
</scm>
</artifact>
</application>
```

My piece of code looks below and works fine when I use the hard coded value of attribute(name), instead of using a variable. I am referencing the line (  my $query  =
    '//application[@name="pos"]'; )

```
my $manifestDoc = $manifestFileParser->parse_file($manifestFile);
my $changeLogDoc = $changeLogParser->parse_file($changeLogXml );
my $changeLogRoot = $changeLogDoc->getDocumentElement;

#my $applicationName = pos;
my $query  = '//application[@name="pos"]';
my $applicationNode = $manifestDoc->findnodes($query);

my $artifactNode = $manifestDoc->createElement('artifact');
$artifactNode->setAttribute("id",$artifactID);
$artifactNode->setAttribute("type",$artifactType);
$artifactNode->setAttribute("cycle",$releaseCycle);
$applicationNode->[0]->appendChild($artifactNode);
```

But if I modify the $query variable to use a variable ($applicationName) instead of a hard coded value of attribute, it gives me a compilation error saying below:

Can't call method "appendChild" on an undefined value at updateManifest.pl line

Modified code:

```
 my $applicationName = "pos" ;
 my $query  = '//application[@name="$applicationName"]';
```

Not sure what is wrong. Anything to do with quotes?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `'//application[@name="$applicationName"]'` means the literal string with those contents – no variables are interpolated with single quotes. If you'd use double quotes, then both `@name` and `$applicationName` would be interpolated.

You have three options:

1. Use double quotes, but escape the `@`:

   ```
   qq(//application[\@name="$applicationName"])
   ```

   The `qq` operator is equivalent to double quotes `"…"` but can have arbitrary delimiters, which avoids the need to escape the `"` inside the string.
2. Concatenate the string:

   ```
   '//application[@name="' . $applicationName . '"]'
   ```

   This often has a tendency to be hard to read. I'd avoid this solution.
3. Use a `sprintf` pattern to build the string from a template:

   ```
   sprintf '//application[@name="%s"]', $applicationName
   ```

   If you don't already know `printf` patterns, you can find them documented in [`perldoc -f sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Comment: XPath also supports single quotes. So I usually go with `"//application[\@name='$applicationName']"`.